# Positive definite functions generated by irreducible representations -- what do people call them?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $\pi:G\to B(H)$ be its *irreducible* unitary representation (one can endow $G$ with topology and claim that $\pi$ is continuous in some sense, this doesn't matter). For a given $x\in H$ the function
$$
f(t)=\langle\pi(t)x,x\rangle,\qquad t\in G
$$
is positive definite, but not all positive definite functions can be represented in this form (with irreducible $\pi$).

> Question: is there a name for these functions (generated by irreducible representations)? What do people call them?

Comment: Consider those normalized $f$, namely $f(1)=1$. Then the $f$ corresponding to irreducible reps are precisely the extremal points among normalized positive definite $f$.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, I understand, thank you. I thought, there is a special name for these functions...

Comment: Yes, it's called "pure"

Comment: "Pure". Thank you! Is this folklore, or I can refer to something?

Comment: It's for instance in the Bekka-Harpe-Valette book http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bachir.bekka/KazhdanTotal.pdf, see Appendix C.5